# The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open - tried everything to close

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

**The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open**

I realize this question is posted numerous times and while I’ve researched it to death and tried most everything, I still am unable to come to a resolution how to fix.  Everything I’ve seen says to close my connections, yet I feel like I’ve done that in quite a few different ways.  I don’t know if this is a coding issue on my end (please give me pointers or suggestions), or if it’s a server configuration issue (which I have no idea how to check).  It seems as though once I hit the error, then other pages are unable to work for a certain period of time.  This continues to happen if more than one user clicks on a page at the same time – it essentially takes the whole site down.  I can recreate by myself if I open up additional browsers and open the page.  I cannot recreate when working locally through Visual Studio (which is why I’m wondering if it’s an IIS config thing).

Is there anything I can do in this code to make sure that the connection is closed so others can reuse?  And/or is there another way to handle the error so the user can try again and not bring everything down?

Thank you to all!

The example below is a shell of what I have, but it causes the problem.  They are slightly different as I’ve tried various ways to get to work from examples on this site.

==================================================================

## Code behind:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField

Partial Class test_testConnections
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then

            LoadMetricDatesToDropDown()
            loadMetricWorkstreamsToDropDown()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub LoadMetricDatesToDropDown()
        Dim draftbit As Boolean = False
        ddlDtSelector.Items.Clear()
        Using oConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("aid1564conn").ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_DSBR_Date_Selections", oConn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                oConn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        While dr.Read
                            Dim li As New ListItem()
                            If dr("dt_status").ToString.ToUpper = "DRAFT" Then
                                li.Text = dr("Metric_Dt") & " (draft)"
                                draftbit = True
                            Else
                                li.Text = dr("metric_dt")
                            End If
                            li.Value = dr("Metric_dt")
                            ddlDtSelector.Items.Add(li)
                        End While
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        If draftbit = True Then ddlDtSelector.SelectedIndex = 1
    End Sub


    Sub loadMetricWorkstreamsToDropDown()
        Using oConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("aid1564conn").ConnectionString)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_DSBR_Get_Workstreams", oConn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                oConn.Open()
                Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    If dr.HasRows Then
                        While dr.Read
                            Dim li As New ListItem()
                            li.Text = dr("workstream_Name")
                            li.Value = dr("workstream_id")
                            workstreams.Items.Add(li)
                        End While
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub


End Class
```

==================================================================

## page

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="testConnections.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test_testConnections" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDtSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="workstreams" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
    <a href="testConnections.aspx">go</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think that the code above could leave the connection open. (The two oConn are two totally unrelated objects) Are you sure you get an error on this code? If yes, on which line?

Comment: Sometimes I receive the "connection not closed" error, which I agree doesn't make sense as I feel like I'm closing everything. once the error hits, then other errors occur as well. The subsequent errors are when it's trying to populate the drop-down - which I don't understand because I have the "hasrows" in there, if there are no rows, then it shouldn't get there...? Is there something you recommend I put in to help check anything?  Thanks for the response, Steve!

Comment: Maybe something else is causing the problem. Have you looked everywhere (all pages) making sure the connection is closed? I don't have time to check this in detail but search for connection pooling settings. You can set in the connection string how many connection to the database are open simultaniously. Maybe you need to set it to 1 in your case.

Comment: the_lotus - I feel like I've looked through all pages, but I could be missing something. I will check again as there must be something somewhere that's keeping it open, I just can't find it - and I can recreate this by loading the same page over and over. I've been reading about connection pooling, but can't seem to find anything to relate to my issue, but I'll keep looking at that as well. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Which DB are u connecting to?

Comment: I mean which version of SQL Server?

Comment: You have connection opened somewhere else, i had the same issue in my application, try to comment the open and close statement in the current code. and then give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are looking for, but if you switch to using a dataset instead of a datareader the connection will close before you start iterating over the rows. This should lesson your exposure to this error.

Also, the `dataadapter.fill` method  will open the connection for you if it not already open, and then close it if it opened it for you, so you will not need to (and shouldn't) explicitly open the connection.

There is possibly something bigger going on here, but that it what i would do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned that you already tried quite a few things then you may have already tried it but in case you have not, here is a sample where I have added some defensive coding:

```
If oConn==null THEN Using oConn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("aid1564conn").ConnectionString)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("usp_DSBR_Get_Workstreams", oConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    if oConn.State != ConnectionState.Open
                oConn.Open()
            Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                If dr.HasRows Then
                    While dr.Read
                        Dim li As New ListItem()
                        li.Text = dr("workstream_Name")
                        li.Value = dr("workstream_id")
                        workstreams.Items.Add(li)
                    End While
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

My VB coding skill are pretty bad so the syntax may be incorrect, but it would be able to convey the basic idea. You should even consider using singleton pattern for connection in future.

Comment: In the above code you may even consider closing the connection if it is opened.